# Does Google Tensorflow support OpenCL

Tags: tensorflow, opencl

Does Google Tensorflow support OpenCL... or is it still only Cuda?

OpenCL does not appear to be supported yet (April 2017) per this open issue - https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22 but I keep reading that support exists -- I might be missing something.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be asked on TF github

Comment: Progress of OpenCL integration into TF can be tracked here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22

Comment: No, and apparently Google didn't show any desire to support it in the future in their repository.

Answer (score 18):

[tf-coriander](https://github.com/hughperkins/tf-coriander) is an implementation of Tensorflow for OpenCL 1.2 GPUs.  It's based on [coriander](https://github.com/hughperkins/coriander), which is a general compiler to run NVIDIA® CUDA™ code on OpenCL 1.2 devices.  Disclosure: I'm the author, of both projects.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was unable to build tf-coriander on Arch Linux; there seems to be an issue on GitHub for this: https://github.com/hughperkins/tf-coriander/issues/59

Answer (score 5):

There is OpenCL support via SYCL on Tensorflow, some features are in, others are in progress: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22#issuecomment-266050835